# Website showing wrong images

Tags: html, image, random, loading

I have a one-page static website. My website is displaying different images than those referenced in the HTML. For example:

```
<img src="img/About_Us_Graphic.png" alt="About us photo" id="aboutUsPic" style="margin: auto;">
```

Will be sometimes displayed as the image that's actually

```
<img src="img/Facebook_icon.png">
```

This happens pretty much randomly. Sometimes the pictures are correct, sometimes they're totally different pictures. And when it's a wrong picture, it isn't consistently the same wrong picture. What causes this? How can I fix it?

My site uses Foundation 5 (not sure if that's relevant). Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Whatever is causing this is not happening in the two lines you included in your post so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found situations similar to the one you described to be the symptom of one of a few causes:

1. Someone is tinkering with the content on the site without you being aware. Ask your team members if they know of anyone who might do this.
2. Your client-side cache is taking over. To remedy this specific problem, go to your browser and clear out the temporary files. Sometimes you have to also clear out cookies and other historical items.
3. Client-side proxies. Sometimes proxy servers store caches of what they serve to reduce the load of their requests. When they work in a round-robin fashion, different servers within the proxy circle might have mismatched content. * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)
4. Load-balanced web servers. I've seen some situations where servers that are load balancing content will hold onto data. In my specific scenario, a memcache was used and would seemingly hold onto content until its index was refreshed.

Without more information about your set-up, there's not much anyone can do. As oxguy3 suggested - there could even be something in your code causing this.

Please try typing the URL of the image directly in your browser and see if it consistantly comes up the same, then try the same url with "?someArbitraryText" after it where "someArbitraryText" is just some random characters.

E.G. instead of "http://my.server.com/img/About_Us_Graphic.png", use "http://my.server.com/img/About_Us_Graphic.png?arbitrary". Most servers that I've encountered will still serve the image, but if a load balancer, proxy, or memcache is involved it will consider this a different URL and load it from the source rather than from some cached file.

I've seen some cases (such as on salesforce clouds) where doing so will bring up different results.

Let us know what you discover. Any little clue could help someone identify and determine the root cause.